# Отправить 1 стикер из пака в телеграмме

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Я создавал телеграмм-бота. Мне нужно отправить один случайный стикер из пака, я пробовал использовать переменную и модуль random но это не работает, есть ли какой-то простой способ сделать это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from random import choice

stickers = ['CAACAgEAAxkBAAITX...SWoV2pOEgBA', '...']  # message.sticker.file_id
bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, choice(stickers))
```